# Preserve query string

Tags: c#, query-string, identityserver4

I am using Identity server 4 with a sitefinity client. I am constructing a url to a secured api with a custom value passed in the query string. (ex: http://localhost:60876/Sitefinity?code=CfDJ8GIUky). I am trying to catch the code's value before redirecting to ID4 however the value disappears. Below is my Notification setup:

```
Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
{
    RedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
    {
        // trying to intercept the request to catch the query string value!
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After two days of researches, here is what I figured out

1- I created a publicly accessible end-point to catch the query string and preserve it

```
public ActionResult Index(string code)
{
    return new ChallengeResult("OpenIdConnect", "http://localhost:60876", code);
}
```

2- The ChallengeResult accepts the code and adds it to AuthenticationProperties

```
var properties = new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = RedirectUri };
if (Code != null)
{
    properties.Dictionary["AccessCode"] = Code;
}
context.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(properties, LoginProvider);
```

3- In the middleware RedirectToIdentityProvider

```
Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
{
    SecurityTokenValidated = context => SecurityTokenValidatedInternal(context),
    RedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
    {
        var code = context.OwinContext.Authentication.AuthenticationResponseChallenge.Properties.Dictionary["AccessCode"];
        context.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("Code", code);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

However the dictionary entry doesn't exist. Am I missing something?